# Using MaterializeCSS with Webpack - Cannot resolve module 'hammerjs'

Tags: hammer.js, webpack, materialize

I'm building a project with webpack. The project uses [`materializecss`](http://materializecss.com/). When I add `materialize.js` to the entry file, it complains with the error below
`Cannot resolve module 'hammerjs'`

When I open the file, I can see the definition there but it appears webpack is unable to identify it. Same thing with weakmap in knockout-es6. My solution to this was to add a reference to `hammer.min.js` in `resolve.alias` but not sure if that is the correct thing to do.

How do I get `webpack` to recognize these dependencies when they are bundled together with the library in question - in this case `materialize.js`?

Comment: Do you have `hammerjs` installed as a dependency to your project (ie. `npm i hammerjs --save`)? If yes, I think Webpack should be able to pick it up as long as it's within [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories).

Comment: @bebraw It worked. Does this not mean that I'll have `hammerjs`. Does this mean `hammerjs` is loaded twice? One from the NPM package and the other that is embedded in materialize.js.

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer with some additional information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you have `hammerjs` installed to your project (ie. `npm i hammerjs --save`), it should find it. As pointed out by @egunays you should also have `import 'expose?Hammer!hammerjs/hammer` to get access to `Hammer` object.

In case you are worried about possible duplication (you can verify this by examining the generated bundle), you can use `webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin`. `webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin` can come in handy as well. That will allow you to separate your app code from a vendor bundle.

See [official optimization docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @bebraw. I'll check out the optimization.

Comment: I had to add this line to make it work: `import 'expose?Hammer!hammerjs/hammer`;

Comment: @eguneys, Thanks! I added that bit to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use ProvidePlugin for this.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "Hammer": "hammerjs/hammer"
}),
```

This does not require an extra loader and is actually recommended in the docs:

> There are cases where you want a module to export itself to the global context. Don't do this unless you really need this. (Better use the ProvidePlugin) [1](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#exposing)